# Populate UITableView with Sections

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, dictionary

I'm trying to populate TableView with sections. Where an artist is the Section Name and all songs of that artist are listed below. In total over 100 artists. Like so

```
FirstArtist
- Song 1
- Song 2

SecondArtist
 - Song 1
 - Song 2

OneMoreArtist...
```

I have an array of objects Song

```
struct Song {

  let songName: String?
  let album: String?
  let artist: String?

}

var songs = [Song]()
```

And an array of all artists names

```
var artists = [String]()
```

As I understand, to populate tableView with sections I need a Dictionary with Artist as key and array of Songs as value, like so

```
var toShow = [String : [Song]]()
```

So, then I'm trying to loop

```
    for artist in artists {
      for song in songs {
        if song.artist == artist {

          toShow[artist] = [song]

//          toShow[artist]?.append(song)

        }
      }
    }
```

But it doesn't work.

Probably I'm going wrong way.

What is the solution in this situation?

Thanks

Update

Made a stuct

```
    struct ArtistWithSongs  { 
       let name: String
       let songs: [Song]

        init(name: String, songs: [Song]) {
      self.name = name
      self.songs = songs
    }   
}
```

and trying to loop

```
var artistWithSongs = [ArtistWithSongs]() 

     for artist in artists {
          for song in songs {
            if artist == song.artist {
              artistWithSongs.append(ArtistWithSongs(name: song, songs: [song]))
            }
          }
        }
```

But apparently, my variant of looping is not correct. Now I'm getting an array of objects contains duplicate keys and only one Song per Key. It looks like

```
[Atrist1 : [Song1], Artist1 : [Song2], Artist1 : [Song3], ...]
```

My question is - What is the right way to make a loop, or is it possible somehow to merge objects with an identical key inside a Dictionary to get this `[Artist1 :[Song1, Song2, Song3]]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to everyone, I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44501262/swift-combining-2-or-more-custom-objects-in-array), it worked for what I was trying to achieve. Roughly like this

```
let toShow = artistWithSongs.reduce([ArtistWithSongs](), { partialResult, artist in

    var dupe = partialResult.filter {$0.songName == group.name }.first
    if let dupeArtist = dupe {
        dupeArtist.songs?.append(contentsOf: artist.songs ?? [])
        return partialResult
    } else {
        var newPartialResult = partialResult
        newPartialResult.append(group)
        return newPartialResult
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to your `Song` struct

```
struct Song {
  let songName: String?
  let album: String?
}
```

create `Artist` one like

```
struct Artist { 
   let name:String
   let songs = [Song]()
}
```

Then create an array of them

```
var artists = [Artist]()
let s1 = Song(songName:"name1",album:"alb1")
let s2 = Song(songName:"name2",album:"alb2")
let artist1 = Artist(name:"art",songs:[s1,s2])
artists.append(artist1)
```

In `numberOfSections` return

```
artists.count
```

In `numberOfRows` return

```
artists[section].songs.count
```

In `cellForRowAt` access

```
let song = artists[indexPath.section].songs[indexPath.row]
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention it before, I have lots of artists, so it is impossible to add each one manually to [Artist] array. Or I misunderstood your solution?

Comment: Thanks, but I'm asking because apparently, my variant of looping is not correct.
Now I'm getting an array of objects contains duplicate keys and only one Song per Key. It looks like [Atrist1 : [Song1],  Artist1 : [Song2],  Artist1 : [Song3], ...].
My question is - How correctly make a loop, or is it possible somehow to merge objects with an identical key inside a Dictionary to get this [Artist1 :[Song1, Song2, Song3]]?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to transform an array of songs (`[Song]`) to a dictionary (`[String : [Song]]`), I would recommend using functional style:

```
self.toShow = songs.reduce([String: [Song]]()) { acc, next in
  // mutable copy
  var acc = acc

  // since artist is optional we need to substitute it with non-optional value if it's nil
  let artist = next.artist ?? "Unknown Artist"

  // if dictionary already has this artist, then append the `next` song to an array
  if acc[artist] != nil {
    acc[artist]?.append(next)
  } else {
  // otherwise create new array
    acc[artist] = [next]
  }

  return acc
}
```

In your table's data source provide the number of sections:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
  return self.toShow.keys.count
}
```

And then you'll face a trouble: for number of rows in section you'll need to know which artist is the section stands for. So, I suggest you to use one more structure, an array of artists so that you keep the order of sections consistent:

```
self.artists = Array(self.toShow.keys).sorted()
```

This way, you can provide your table with following numbers of sections and rows:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
  return self.artists.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
  let artist = self.artists[section] // get the artist's name
  return self.toShow[artist]?.count ?? 0
}
```